# Lightswitch - how to customize create user screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I need to customize create user screen in Lightswitch application. Like I need an additional field in user creation screen, the purpose is to store user location. Is it possible in lightswitch or any workaround there? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to customize the built-in screen for user/role management in LightSwitch.  But LightSwitch is based on the ASP.NET Membership infrastructure.  So you could create your own web page outside of LightSwitch that manages the users, and simply use the ASP.NET Membership APIs to write the data in the database.  LightSwitch will be able to read the user data it cares about from any new users you add to the database even if it was done outside of LightSwitch.  In your case, since you want to add custom field associated to the user, you would use the ASP.NET ProfileProvider to store that information.  But the bottom line is that LightSwitch doesn't provide any functionality for you to manage/view this data; you'd have to build that yourself.

Comment: thanks for clear explanation, Ok it seems, I have to develop my own web page for this. I think there should be some mechanism provided for these screens to be customized in future.